# MySQL query for displaying employees who are not assigned on a project

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently creating a application that will assign employees on a certain project. These employees can be removed to a project and can be put back to the project again.

I have these tables:

```
employees_tbl
id
first name
last name

projects_tbl
id
name

project_assignment_tbl
id
project_id
employee_id
date_removed (NULL)
```

So every time we removed a user to the project, the `date_removed` column in the `project_assignment_tbl` will be date/timestamped, and everytime we add an employee to the project, a new data will be inserted in the `project_assignment_tbl` The reason why i'm doing this it's because in my application i also want to get the project assignment history.

So in my application, I will go to a specific project,(`/project/1`), then I will assign an employee from there.

My question here is that how can I display/query a list of employees that are not assigned to the certain project? This may sound easy, but i am having problems on how to display the user that were assigned before and they were removed in the project, but i want to display them again because they were removed to the certain project.

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Not assigned now or never have been assigned?  Post some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I have a suggestion that will remove all that pain, remove the column 'date_removed' from 'project_assignment_tbl', add a new table that serves as a log for removal operations, now every time you want to remove an employee you just need to delete the row from the table and add a row in the history log table, this will simplify every thing!

Comment: @AbdoAdel - Simply having a boolean in the _existing_ table would make more sense. Could use `is_deleted` (true/false). When you delete it, set `is_deleted` to true, and add the timestamp to `date_removed`. Makes more sense than shuffling data between tables... If you ever want to bring it back, change `is_deleted` back to false and remove the timestamp from `date_removed`.

Comment: @WadeShuler but he needs to keep track of all removal operations

Comment: Could possibly set `employee_id` to NULL. Everything in `project_assignment_tbl` with a NULL `employee_id` would be a project that isn't assigned to a person. -- I skimmed it because he didn't take the time to provide any code..

Comment: @PM77-1 yes you are correct, what I meant was not assigned now or never has been assigned to the project.

Comment: Fwiw, I disagree with abdo's suggestion. However I don't understand why you would keep track of an unassigned date but not an assigned date.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean never assigned to a project:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employees_tbl e
WHERE e.id NOT IN (SELECT employee_id
    FROM project_assignment_tbl
    WHERE project_id=1234) // sample project ID
```

If you mean not currently assigned to a project:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employees_tbl e
WHERE e.id NOT IN (SELECT employee_id
    FROM project_assignment_tbl
    WHERE project_id=1234 AND date_removed IS NULL)
```